# Display columns headers values in rows with PHP table

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have this table:

[image]

And time ago I was looking the way to make it possible display columns in rows with PHP table from MySQL data and I found it! Someone here help me with that.

But now I see a mistake, error in some line because I need to show the "prov_name" values from DB in the `<th>` not the field name from the table , I mean like this [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/LLSst/).

Now I see that the error is in this line:

```
<th colspan="2"><?php echo "prov_name $x"; ?></th>
```

I know that is wrong because should be say $prov_name or something with variable because the prov_name always is different.

This is the code (all works fine except that):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();    
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$data = array();
$query="SELECT * from provprices WHERE CA_id= ".$CA_id;
$results = mysql_query($query);

$db->setQuery("SELECT * from provprices");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $data[$row['prov_name']][] = $row;
}

$keys = array_keys($data);
$size = count($keys);
$vals = array();
// grouping:
// if there are six (cam1 to cam6)
// then group them by cam1, ... to cam6, then repeat until theres no more left
while(count($data) > 0) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if(!empty($data[$key])) {
            $vals[] = array_shift($data[$key]);
        } else {
            unset($data[$key]); // remove them if empty
        }
    }
}
$vals = array_chunk($vals, $size); // split them by how many prov_names
?>
<div class="datagrid" id='Three'>
<table class="prices" >
    <!-- PROV NAMES -->
    <tr><?php for($x = 1; $x <= $size; $x++): ?>

////////////////////////////////////// THIS LINE
        <th colspan="2"><?php echo "prov_name $x"; ?></th>
////////////////////////////////////// THIS LINE

    <?php endfor; ?></tr>

    <!-- unitval totvals -->
    <tr><?php for($x = 1; $x <= $size; $x++): ?>
<td style="background-color: #00CDB9; border-bottom: 4px solid #006f7d; color: white;  font-weight: bold; border-right: 4px solid #006f7d;">Valor Unitario
</td>
<td style="background-color: #00CDB9; border-bottom: 4px solid #006f7d; color: white;  font-weight: bold; ">
Valor Total
</td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>

    <!-- the grouped values -->
    <?php foreach($vals as $val): ?>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($val as $v): ?>
            <td><?php echo $v['unitval']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $v['totval']; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: hi. i remember this question. i think i was the one who answered this. why did you change it to mysql? i answered this with pdo lol. i think i understand now. instead of literal prov_name. you want to print the corresponding value to that prov_name. is that correct? if yes. where do you get them? maybe you need another query

Comment: @Ghost ! Yeah you're the only one that help me in that question.
Because PDO don't works in my server, I don't know why. I show this in joomla, so when i change it works like a charm, except this part. 
Yes the value for that prov_name like the first [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/LLSst). 
I get them from the same table(image), the first one is CAM1, the second one is CAM2..etc.. until CAM6 but not always are 6 prov_name's sometimes are just 2 or 3.
After someone insert the info [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/fK8sn/) someone see the info with this.

Comment: in your fiddle. i can see camii, cam, etc. is this in the same table? what is the name of this column?

Comment: Yeah, is an example because always the prov_name is different.
The column name is prov_name, so i the query should be `Select prov_name from provprices(table name) where CA_id = ".$CA_id;` and your magic.. Thanks @Ghost, I Hope you can help me.

Comment: so this is in the same table? we already assigned it in the keys you can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already close, just print them directly:

```
<!-- PROV NAMES -->
<tr>
<?php foreach($keys as $prov_name): ?>
    <th><?php echo $prov_name; ?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```